Remove port 443 from downloadUri in Artifactory
We are having issues with helm login (and potentially with docker login when we start using it).
While our domain for Artifactory is https://artifactory.domain.com, when we try to add Helm, the URL has ":443" in the download URI.
Helm differentiates between the domains "artifactory.domain.com" and "artifactory.domain.com:443". This requires us to set the --pass-credentials parameter, which I would prefer not to do.
Is there any way to set the download URI in Artifactory to remove the port from the domain?
{
  "repo" : "*-helm-local",
  "path" : "/*-1.0.12.tgz",
  "created" : "2024-03-20T08:04:11.708Z",
  "createdBy" : "*",
  "downloadUri" : "https://artifactory.domain.com:443/artifactory/*-helm-local/*-1.0.12.tgz",
  "mimeType" : "application/x-gzip",
  "size" : "2463",
  "checksums" : {
    "sha1" : "*",
    "md5" : "*",
    "sha256" : "*"
  },
  "originalChecksums" : {
    "sha256" : "*"
  },
  "uri" : "https://artifactory.domain.com:443/artifactory/*-helm-local/*-1.0.12.tgz"
}

I tried "custom domain" in settings, but it does not look like to have an affect.
